# How do I retrieve data from tables in Django that are not directly joined?

Tags: django, elasticsearch

I have a Response table:

```
class Response(models.Model):
    Question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, default=13, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Response = models.TextField()
    Client = models.ForeignKey(ClientDetail, default=8, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Planit_location = models.ForeignKey(Planit_location, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    Document = models.ForeignKey(Document, default=0, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Response
```

I am able to retrieve data from other tables that it is directly joined to e.g. Questions, Topic, Client:

views.py

```
clientList = ClientDetail.objects.all().order_by('Client_name')
topicList = Topic.objects.all().order_by('Topic_name')
```

Now I want to retrieve "Sector Name" from my Sector Table:

```
class Sector(models.Model):
    Sector_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Sector_name')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Sector_name
```

Which is joined to my Client Table:

```
class ClientDetail(models.Model):
    Sector = models.ForeignKey(Sector, default=8, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Client_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Client_name')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['Client_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Client_name
```

I cannot use the same method i did with Client as it cannot find a "Sector_id" field in the Response table:

```
sectorList = Sector.objects.all().order_by('Sector_name')
**THIS DOES NOT WORK**
```

As of this moment, i am only able to retrieve "Sector_id" from my Client table but i what i want is the "Sector Name"

Is there something i should be adding into my documents.py file? As i cannot use the same method i did for previous models:

```
class ResponseDocument20(DocType):
    Client = fields.NestedField(properties={
        'Client_name': fields.TextField(),
        'pk': fields.IntegerField(),
    }, include_in_root=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Response

        fields = [
            'Response',
        ]
        related_models = [ClientDetail]

    def get_instances_from_related(self, related_instance):
        if isinstance(related_instance, ClientDetail):
            return related_instance.response_set.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use double underscore to reach referenced model fields, annotate to make a readable alias:

```
clientList = ClientDetail.objects.all() \
.annotate(Sector_name=F('Sector__Sector_name')) \
.order_by('Client_name')
```

Now your queryset has `Sector_name` field with `Sector__Sector_name` (`FK->Sector->Sector_name`) values.

`F()` docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions

Comment: I get an error when i try to implement that.

ProgrammingError at /search_es20/
column app_sector.id does not exist
LINE 1: ..."app_sector" ON ("app_clientdetail"."Sector_id" = "app_secto...

Comment: `column app_sector.id does not exist` it's saying that your Sector model is missing `id` column. Probably you have some unapplied migrations.